# How to POST with Array inside Array Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There are my mongoose schemas. I guess its ok. (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  "itemNo": {
    "type": "String"
  }
});

const mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  "items":[itemSchema],
  "title": {
    "type": "String"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "String"
  },
  "pic": {
    "type": "String"
  },
  "star": {
    "type": "Boolean"
  },
  "category": {
    "type": "String"
  },
  "date": {
    "type": "Date"
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('dashboards', mySchema);
```

But im having trouble with post method. How can fix the code?
When i post my json, its returning with empty "items".

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const post = new Model1({
        title: req.body.title,
        data: req.body.data,
        pic: req.body.pic,
        star: req.body.star,
        category: req.body.category,
        items: [req.body.items]  
    });
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. It's easier for you to insert into the question and easier for us to debug.

Comment: Sorry, i edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my project like this. My problem is solved.
Here is my schemas.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  "itemNo": {
    "type": "String"
  },
});

const mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  "title": {
    "type": "String"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "String"
  },
  "pic": {
    "type": "Date"
  },
  "star": {
    "type": "Boolean"
  },
  "category": {
    "type": "String"
  },
  "items": [itemSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('dashboards', mySchema);
```

This is my post request.

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const post = new Model1({
        title: req.body.title,
        data: req.body.data,
        pic: req.body.pic,
        star: req.body.star,
        category: req.body.category,
        items: req.body.items
    });
```